# Are there formal linguistic understandings of misspelled words?

Tags: orthography, theoretical-linguistics

For example, I will assume that people make mistakes in spelling because, often, the misspelled words look similar enough to the intended words, so the communication can be made smoothly, but I wonder if there are any formal studies about this?

In practice, it would be great if there are also any guidelines to distinguish the misspellings that do not hinder the communication and the ones do.

For example, I believe these two misspellings of "misspelling" will play different roles in communications:

- msspellings
- missellings

but how to formally define these differences (and hopefully even quantify them)?

Comment: I think words are covered under morphology which talks about affixes (prefixes, suffixes), base words, inflections, derivations etc.  The spellings naturally become part of this.  Your examples (msspellings and missellings) sound like typos that are possible, and as you mention these won't go unnoticed as easy as the words judgements and judgments. Not sure if this is defined.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but there certainly ought to be one! There are definitely quantifiable causalities at work, and it'd make for a stimulating study. Perhaps it might lead to techniques for amelioration, even.